# Why doesn't this MySQL update work?

Tags: mysql

have a table called `meterreadings`.  I need to copy the attribute `meterreading` from one row to the other.

Here is a sample of data:

```
 id   |  meterreadingdate  |  meterreading  |  meterreadingtype_id | created
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1    |  2011-10-01        |  0             |  1                   | 2011-10-15
 2    |  2011-10-01        |  500           |  2                   | 2011-10-15
```

So basically, I want to copy all of the `meterreading` values based on the  `meterreadingtype_id` column so that `meterreadingtype_id` value of 2 will copy over to 1.

The data should look like this when done:

```
 id   |  meterreadingdate  |  meterreading  |  meterreadingtype_id | created
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1    |  2011-10-01        |  500           |  1                   | 2011-10-15
 2    |  2011-10-01        |  500           |  2                   | 2011-10-15
```

Notice I copied the 500 over because the `meterreadingtype_id` was a 1 and I go the value from the next row because it was a 2.

Here is the query I am using:

```
update meterreadings mr1
set meterreading = 
(
    select
        meterreading 
    from meterreadings
    where
        meterreadingtype_id = 2
        and meterreadingdate = mr1.meterreadingdate
        and location_id = mr1.location_id
        and created = mr1.created
        and asset_id = mr1.asset_id
)
where asset_id in (select id from assets where model_id in (select id from models where make_id IN (81, 82)))
and meterreadingtype_id = 1
```

We are using MySQL 5 and InnoDB tables if that helps.

Comment: Sorry, having trouble posting.  Corporate firewall is blocking my actual update statement.

Comment: Do you get an error or 0 rows get updated?

Comment: @Michael  Thanks for the edit.  Corp firewall was blocking the update statement from being posted.

Comment: I get:  `You can't specify a target table 'mr1' for UPDATE in FROM clause`

Comment: It helps to break these complicated SQL queries down.  Do each of the inner selects give you the correct results and do you get the row you want to update if you do `select * from meterreadings` instead of an update.

Comment: yes.  The inner selects work.  I can make this a select instead of an update and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is failing because you cannot modify a table and select from that same table in a subquery.

See [Subquery Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html)

> One restriction is that a subquery's outer statement must be one of: SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SET, or DO. Another restriction is that currently you cannot modify a table and select from the same table in a subquery. This applies to statements such as DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, UPDATE, and (because subqueries can be used in the SET clause) LOAD DATA INFILE.

I think you can get around this with some JOIN trickery:

```
UPDATE meterreadings AS tgt
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM meterreadings
  WHERE meterreadingtype_id = 2
  ) AS src
ON tgt.meterreadingdate = src.meterreadingdate
   AND tgt.location_id = src.location_id
   AND tgt.created = src.created
   AND tgt.asset_id = src.asset_id
SET tgt.meterreading = src.meterreading
```

I'm no MySQL expert, but I believe this works because MySQL processes the subquery first and stores the result in memory as a temporary table, which doesn't change during the UPDATE. A side effect of this is that if the result of the subquery is large, then you'll chew up a ton of (or run out of) memory.

The only way (as far as I know) to get around the memory issue is to pare down the subquery using criteria that aren't directly related to the update target. For example, if you were to do these updates as part of a nightly process, make the inner SELECT only return rows created in the past ~24 hours.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am getting.  Is there a better way?

Comment: I actually found an even easier way but I awarded you the answer.  What I actually did was deleted all the 1's and then changed the 2's to 1's.  lol.  Did the same thing